# get images from directory and ad to ul

Tags: php, html

I'm using a responsive pattern from Brad Frost's library to create an image grid (beta version here: http://yogeshsimpson.com/fry). I want to have three folders of images for the three portfolio categories that my client can just drop images into.

From there I think php is the right tool to get all the images from a folder, wrap in li and a tags and have them added to the ul. So on the homepage you see images from all three directories, and on the "lighting" page for example, you see only images from that directory, etc.

Again I'm assuming this is fairly easy to do with php, but it's a bit beyond my grasp. Any help would be appreciated. Much thanks.

Comment: save just the file name in the db and store it on the server, than mach the names, and point to the saved folder

Comment: I'm looking for the correct method to get all images from a directory, wrap each one individually in a '<li>' tag and an '<a>' tag and add them to a '<ul>'.

Comment: or if you want imeages from a folder so badly, check: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

Comment: Ok, so apparently this is a stupid question. Open to suggestions on how to make it "clear and useful". Just trying to learn here. Thanks for the help @LeventeNagy.

Comment: its not a stupid question, but stackowerflow is i a help out, not a we do it for you, google it

Comment: @user783154 Have a look at my answer, I think it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work, run it from within the folder you wish to list the files.

```
<?php

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
   while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
      {
          if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
      {

            $thelist .= '<li><a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>' . "<br>";

          }
       }
  closedir($handle);
  }       
?>
<P>List of files:</p>
<P><?=$thelist?></p>
```

### Or:

```
<?php

// if running from your root and wish to list files from 'images' sub-folder
// use $dir = 'images';
$dir = '.'; // The directory containing the files.

// *.* will list all files. You can use *.jpg to list just JPG files, etc.
$ext = '*.*'; // will list ALL files
?> 

<ul> <?php foreach (glob($dir . '/*' . $ext) as $file) { ?> 
<li><a href="<?php echo $dir . "/" . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file); ?></a></li>

<?php } ?> </ul>
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. What if I want to display the images rather than list the file names?

Comment: @user783154 Ouuh..now that's a different ball of wax! lol! let me see what I can do, can't promise anything though.

Comment: @user783154 You can use this for the 2nd body of code, you might want to play with it a bit but it works `<li><a href="<?php echo $dir . "/" . $file ?>"><?php echo basename($file); ?><img src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></a></li>`

Comment: @user783154 And use `$ext = '*.jpg';` instead of `$ext = '*.*';` or depending which file extension you wish to be shown.

Comment: @user783154 Or use `<li><a href="<?php echo $dir . "/" . $file ?>"><img src="<?php echo $file; ?>"></a></li>` not to show the filename, just the image.

Comment: @user783154 How are you making out?

Comment: @user783154 If you feel that my answer helped you, then in order to mark your question as "answered", please consider clicking the checkmark to accept, so that it won't stay in the "unanswered" category.

Comment: It works! I removed '$dir . "/" .' Thanks a ton Fred. What if I want to add a class to the <a> tag or look in another directory for the linked image?

Comment: @user783154 Great, and you're welcome. If you want to add a class, be sure to wrap it inside single quotes and not double. For example: `<a class='class_name' href="<?php echo $dir . "/" . $file ?>">` ought to do it. And to look in another folder, I would think that using `$dir = '../other_folder';` will work if executed from another folder.

Comment: ah, but the value declared for $dir is included in the $file. Adding a subdirectory to the path would be fine, but anything in the $dir = '/' gets put first...

Comment: @user783154 Depends how and where it's used. There is surely room for improvement.

Comment: And just to clarify, I want to use the <a> tag to link to another directory that will have a bigger version of the image for a lightbox, but it can have the same file name. Or it could reside in the same directory and have an appended file name such as image_big.jpg

Comment: @user783154 Hm... not quite sure how that could work, but it's worth a shot. Since it's inside a `foreach`, that could cause a problem and is fetching all files and not the one file in particular.

Comment: Right. Is there any way to define a second $dir tag up front to use in the href? Ore a way to append the file name before the extension?

Comment: @user783154 That, I don't know. A script that would allow something like that, stands at having a lot more code than my 7-liner ;-)